# How to deal with Netty "Last write attempt timed out; force-closing the connection." exception?

Tags: netty

After recent deploy I found many errors like this on my production server :

> Last write attempt timed out; force-closing the connection.

At the moment I'm getting ~5 such errors per hour from different hosts.
I looked through the code in Netty `SslHandler` and see that this exception is expected when `close_notify` event is not fully sent to the receiver (according to the comments).

However, I never saw this error before. That makes me think that it may be some kind of wrong pipeline configuration issue. So at the moment, I'm not sure if that my error or just the network issue.

Netty version 4.1.22.Final

Epoll and ssl enabled with netty-tcnative-boringssl-static 2.0.7.Final

I made few unit tests but without any luck.

Does anybody have any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I was able to fix the issue. Seems that problem was in the pipeline configuration.

Pipeline with bug:

```
.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(appIdleTimeout, 0, 0))
.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()))
.addLast(appChannelStateHandler);
```

Pipeline without the issue:

```
.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(appIdleTimeout, 0, 0))
.addLast(appChannelStateHandler)
.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()))
```

Where `appChannelStateHandler` is `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        log.trace("State handler. App timeout disconnect. Event : {}. Closing.", ((IdleStateEvent) evt).state());
        ctx.close();
    } else {
        ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(evt);
    }
}
```

Probably the issue was that `ctx.close();` was called both in `SslHandler` and in `appChannelStateHandler`. At least this is something that comes to mind first. I still not sure - is that netty issue or wrong pipeline configuration? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem locally anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do except higher the timeout. This means you could not write out the data fast enough to the remote peer, which most likely means the remote peer did not read fast enough. Another cause could be that you block the EventLoop and so it can not make any progress in a timely manner.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/7799... Can you verify the fix ?